# Spark SQL refer to columns programmatically

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am about to develop a function which uses spark sql to perform an operation per column. In this function I need to refer to the columns name:

```
val input = Seq(
    (0, "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    (1, "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    (0, "d", "a", "jkl", "d"),
    (0, "d", "g", "C", "D"),
    (1, "A", "d", "t", "k"),
    (1, "d", "c", "C", "D"),
    (1, "c", "B", "C", "D")
  ).toDF("TARGET", "col1", "col2", "col3TooMany", "col4")
```

The following example explicitly referring to columns via `'column` works fine.

```
val pre1_1 = input.groupBy('col1).agg(mean($"TARGET").alias("pre_col1"))
val pre2_1 = input.groupBy('col1, 'TARGET).agg(count("*") / input.filter('TARGET === 1).count alias ("pre2_col1"))

input.as('a)
    .join(pre1_1.as('b), $"a.col1" === $"b.col1").drop($"b.col1")
    .join(pre2_1.as('b), ($"a.col1" === $"b.col1") and ($"a.TARGET" === $"b.TARGET")).drop($"b.col1").drop($"b.TARGET").show

When referring to the columns programmatically they can no longer be resolved. When 2 joins are performed one after the other which worked fine for the code snippet above.
```

I could observe that for this code snippet the first and initial `col1` of `df` was moved from the beginning to the end. Probably this is the reason that it can no longer be resolved. 
But so far I could not figure it out how to access the column when only passing a string / how to properly reference the colnames in a function.

```
val pre1_1 = input.groupBy("col1").agg(mean('TARGET).alias("pre_" + "col1"))
val pre2_1 = input.groupBy("col1", "TARGET").agg(count("*") / input.filter('TARGET === 1).count alias ("pre2_" + "col1"))
  input.join(pre1_1, input("col1") === pre1_1("col1")).drop(pre1_1("col1"))
    .join(pre2_1, (input("col1") === pre2_1("col1")) and (input("TARGET") === pre2_1("TARGET"))).drop(pre2_1("col1")).drop(pre2_1("TARGET"))
```

as well as an alternative approach like:

```
df.as('a)
      .join(pre1_1.as('b), $"a.${col}" === $"b.${col}").drop($"b.${col}")
```

did not succeed as `$"a.${col}"` no longer was resolved to `a.Column` but rather `df("a.col1")` which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In complex cases always use unique aliases to reference columns with shared lineage. This is the only way to ensure **correct** and stable behavior.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val pre1_1 = input.groupBy("col1").agg(mean('TARGET).alias("pre_" + "col1")).alias("pre1_1")
val pre2_1 = input.groupBy("col1", "TARGET").agg(count("*") / input.filter('TARGET === 1).count alias ("pre2_" + "col1")).alias("pre2_1")

input.alias("input")
  .join(pre1_1, col("input.col1") === col("pre1_1.col1"))
  .join(pre2_1, (col("input.col1") === col("pre2_1.col1")) and (col("input.TARGET") === col("pre2_1.TARGET")))
```

If you check logs you actually see warnings like:

> WARN Column: Constructing trivially true equals predicate, 'col1#12 = col1#12'. Perhaps you need to use aliases

and code you use work only because there are "special cases" in Spark source.

In simple case like this just use equi-join syntax:

```scala
input.join(pre1_1, Seq("col1"))
  .join(pre2_1, Seq("col1", "TARGET"))
```